# How to convert integer to char array[]?

Tags: c

Please read till the end.

I have a function that loops through a character array until it finds the '\0' end character in a character array.

I want to convert the integer

```
int number = 128;
```

To a character array

```
char data[] = ""; // data[] = "128"  , contains '\0'
```

I have found several ways suggested (memcpy, itoa) but I want a conversion that adds the '\0' automatically at the end.

Comment: About that comment: String literals in *double quotes* in C have NUL char at end, so `"128\0"` would have 2 NUL chars.

Answer (score -1):

itoa() automatically adds a null terminator.
See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/